# Trying to script rsync using pam_exec

Tags: bash, rsync, pam

I'm trying to write a bash script that will execute rsync when called by `pam_exec`. I've tried a couple different ways, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
When I try to run the script at login by adding

```
session     optional      pam_exec.so /usr/bin/local/sync.sh
```

to my `sshd` file, it gives me an exit code of 12.

If I log in and then manually run my script, it allows me to connect to the remote server, and it lists my files, but it doesn't actually sync anything.

I have tried the code below using buth `$USER` and `$PAM_USER`. `$PAM_USER` doesn't work at all.

```
#!/bin/sh 
rsync -azv -e ssh $USER@remote_server:/home/html/$USER/ /home/html/$USER
```

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `pam_exec` explains that the module provides `$PAM_USER`, not `$USER`:

> the following PAM items are exported as environment variables: `PAM_RHOST`, `PAM_RUSER`, `PAM_SERVICE`, `PAM_TTY`, `PAM_USER` and `PAM_TYPE` [...]

On my Debian based system I added this line just before the entry for `pam_motd`

```
# Run a script on login
session    optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/etc/pam_exec.sh
```

I then created the test script, remembering to make it executable:

```
cat >/usr/local/etc/pam_exec.sh <<'EOF'; chmod a+rx /usr/local/etc/pam_exec.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
test open_session = "$PAM_TYPE" && {
    echo
    date
    echo "PAM_USER=$PAM_USER, USER=$USER."

} >>/tmp/pam_exec.log

exit 0
EOF
```

Finally, I opened a new login session to my test system, and saw that on session start I received information such as this in my log file `/tmp/pam_exec.log`:

```
Mon Nov  9 23:32:52 GMT 2015
PAM_USER=roaima, USER=.
```

To implement your requirement you would need to use a script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -azq -e ssh "$PAM_USER"@remote_server:/home/html/"$PAM_USER"/ /home/html/"$PAM_USER" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Notice that all output from `rsync` is discarded. This is necessary to ensure that client/server applications using `ssh` as a transport do not get hit by unexpected output before they can start their negotiation. If you really want to present it to the user, I would recommend you write it to a user-specific log file such as `"$HOME/.pam_exec.log"` and then use a line like this in the user's `.profile` to output it after the login process has completed:

```
if test -t 1 -a -s "$HOME/.pam_exec.log"
then
    echo "Prelogin results"
    sed 's/^/| /' "$HOME/.pam_exec.log"
fi
```

It's not immune to a race condition, but IME most users don't login simultaneously multiple times to the same server. If you find this scenario is common there are ways to deal with it.